# Connection refused with kubectl on EC2 ubuntu instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I installed docker-go-kubernetes on an ubuntu EC2 AWS instance using this guide: http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/

I have kubectl installed but when I run a test:

`kubectl run my-nginx --image=nginx --replicas=2 --port=80`

I receive and error:

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you
>   specify the right host or port?

How do I specify the host or port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't configure your `kubectl`.

You need to either place proper kubeconfig into `~/.kube/config` or provide in during call like:

`kubectl --kubeconfig=kubeconfig run my-nginx --image=nginx --replicas=2 --port=80`